How to deploy a lambda with multiple root endpoints from one apigateway via serverless?
I am using serverless to deploy REST API in AWS. I have 3 serverless yml files.
serverlessApi.yml: it deploys the API gateway itself plus two paths /v1 and /v2.
serverlessProduct.yml: it deploys querying product API for both v1 and v2.
serverlessCustomer.yml: it deploy endpoints for customer for both v1 and v2.
The problem I have is that I can't deploy a lambda for both v1 and v1 path from one serverless stack. For example, below is my lambda config for product:
provider:
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: xxxxxxxxxx
    restApiRootResourceId: / # select the root of the api gateway
    websocketApiId: xxxxxxxxxx
    description: Some Description

...
function:
  - getProduct:
    handler: x
    events:
      - http:
        method: GET
        path: /v1/product
      - http:
        method: GET
        path: /v2/product

When I deploy this stack, it gives me an error saying Resource handler returned message: "Another resource with the same parent already has this name: v1. It seems serverless tries to create the path /v1 during deployment which has been already created before. I'd like to make the serverlessApi.yml to deploy both v1 and v2 paths and let serverlessCustomer.yml and serverlessProduct.yml to share them. How can I achieve it?
